# Proving a set is a subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Haven't done this for a long time, just want to know if this is the right method for a really simple example. Say we have two (obviously equal) sets $$A= \Big\{\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} : a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R,  a+b=c \Big\}$$ $$B= \Big\{\begin{bmatrix}e & f\\g & h\end{bmatrix} : e,f,g,h \in \Bbb R,  e+f=g \Big\}$$

Prove $A\subseteq B$.

Let $a\in A$, such that $a=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$. Choose $a=e$, $b=f$, $c=g$ and $d=h$. Then $a=\begin{bmatrix}e & f\\g & h\end{bmatrix}$ where $e+f=g$, hence $a\in B$ and $A\subseteq B$.

Thanks!

Edit: I chose an obviously equal example on purpose. It was a question about the method of proving rather than the actual example.

Comment: Well if $A=B$ then it holds that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$...

Comment: This is a valid method. However, generally the symbols used are not considered part of the definition as such, that is, whether you choose to use $a,b,c,d$ or $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_4$ has no bearing on the elements.

Comment: @copper.hat So for instance, you could let $a\in A$ and define $a$ as I did. Then say $a+b=c$, hence $a\in B$?

Comment: Well, not really. What I mean is that the particular symbols used don't matter. If I write $\{(x,y) | x+y = 1\}$, this is generally considered the same (without comment) as $\{(u,v) | u+v = 1\}$. The symbols $x,y,u,v$ are just place holders. There is nothing wrong with your answer, just that generally that would be considered overkill in context.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes this is what I meant, maybe I did not write it well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that works. In general, you take something from $A$, and show it has whatever property necessary to belong to $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Since, as you say, it's obvious that $A = B$, it's obvious that $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: I chose an obvious example on purpose. It was more about the method of proving, but thanks anyway.

Comment: In general, when you have $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta$, being $\alpha$ and $\beta$ statements and you want to prove $\beta$, you normally start by assuming $\alpha$ and then you try to infer $\beta$. This matches for all statements, in particular, when $\alpha \equiv a \in A$ and $\beta \equiv a \in B$. So then you did it right :)

Answer (score 0):

It is by definition of two sets being equal that
$$A=B\iff A\subseteq B\land B\subseteq A$$

Here is a simple proof for your sake:

$$A= \Big\{\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} : a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R,  a+b=c \Big\}$$ $$B= \Big\{\begin{bmatrix}e & f\\g & h\end{bmatrix} : e,f,g,h \in \Bbb R,  e+f=g \Big\}$$

After a change of variables...
$$A= \Big\{\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1 & \alpha_2\\\alpha_3 & \alpha_4\end{bmatrix} : \alpha_n\in \Bbb R,  \alpha_1+\alpha_2=\alpha_3 \Big\}$$ $$B= \Big\{\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1 & \alpha_2\\\alpha_3 & \alpha_4\end{bmatrix} : \alpha_n\in \Bbb R,  \alpha_1+\alpha_2=\alpha_3 \Big\}$$
Therefore $A=B\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$